# Research: Looking for a sequence that produce variation's of Pascal's triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Prologue

I am an undergraduate so if my terminology or approach seem inappropriate/confusing please explain in the comments.

I created a notation where

$$F(0 \rightarrow n,x) = [\hspace{1mm}F(0 ,x),\hspace{2mm}F(1, x),\hspace{2mm}F(2, x), \ldots,\hspace{2mm} F(n-2,x),\hspace{2mm}F(n-1,x),\hspace{2mm}F( n,x)\hspace{1mm}]$$

Last semester in Calculus 1 I created a function noted as $\mu(e,f)$ where $f$,$e$ are just positive integers including 0 and if c is any numerical value then $\mu(c,c)=0$ and $\frac{d \mu(c,c)}{dx}=0$.  The interesting part was $$\frac{d \mu(e,f)}{dx}=\mu(e+1,f)+\mu(e,f+1)$$  I then figured out by playing around with the function that if $f>e + c$ for any real c then: $$\frac{d^\lambda \mu(e,f)}{(dx)^\lambda}=\sum_{i=0}^{\lambda}\binom{\lambda}{i}\mu(e+i,f+\lambda-i)$$

I figured this out by putting the Function into Pascal's Triangle,  where each row represents the derivative of the row before it.  I will call this triangle Pascal's Triangle for Functions (PTF).  For clarity I made some stuff that makes the patterns easier to see. In the equation $\frac{d \mu(e,f)}{dx}=\mu(e+1,f)+\mu(e,f+1)$, The $\mu(e+1,f)$ will be presented as $\swarrow$ and $\mu(e,f+1)$ will be presented as $\searrow$.  Let $G(j,k) = \mu(e+j,f+k)$ therefore $\frac{d G(j,k)}{dx}=G(j+1,k)+G(j,k+1)$.

\begin{equation}
G(0,0)\\
\swarrow\searrow \\
G(1,0)+G(0,1)\\
\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\\
G(2,0)+2G(1,1)+G(0,2)\\
\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow \\
G(3,0)+3G(2,1)+3G(1,2)+G(0,3)\\
\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow \\
G(4,0)+4G(3,1)+6G(2,2)+4G(1,3)+G(0,4)\\
\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow \\
G(5,0)+5G(4,1)+10G(3,2)+10G(2,3)+5G(1,4)+G(0,5)\\
\ldots
\end{equation}

Anyways knowing $\mu(c,c)=0$ and $e$,$f$ are finite then let $\alpha = e-f$ so $\mu(f+\alpha,f)$.  I as the writer am going to ignorantly for the sake of clarity assume if a function ever becomes 0 that it no longer exists and therefore loses it's significant.  Therefore 0 will be replaced with white space for these illustrations.

If $\alpha=1$ and $e =0$

\begin{equation}
\hspace{5mm}\mu(0,1)\\
\hspace{5mm}\swarrow\searrow\\
[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(1,1)\hspace{1mm}]+\mu(0,2)\\
\hspace{26mm}\swarrow\searrow\\
\hspace{25mm}\mu(1,2)+\mu(0,3)\\
\hspace{28mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\\
\hspace{15mm}[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(2,2)\hspace{1mm}]+2\mu(1,3)+\mu(0,4)\\
\hspace{50mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\\
\hspace{51mm}2\mu(2,3)+3\mu(1,4)+\mu(0,5)\\
\hspace{58mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{10mm}\swarrow\searrow\\
\hspace{45mm}2[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(3,3)\hspace{1mm}]+2\mu(2,4)+3\mu(1,5)+\mu(0,6)\\
\hspace{78mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{12mm}\swarrow\searrow\hspace{10mm}\swarrow\searrow\\
\hspace{75mm}2\mu(3,4)+5\mu(2,5)+4\mu(1,6)+\mu(0,7)\\
\ldots
\end{equation}

if $\alpha=2,e=0$:
\begin{equation}
\hspace{5mm}\mu(0,2)\\
\hspace{5mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\\
\hspace{5mm}\mu(1,2)+\mu(0,3)\\
\hspace{8mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{2mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\\
\hspace{0mm}[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(2,2)\hspace{1mm}]+2\mu(1,3)+\mu(0,4)\\
\hspace{28mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{2mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\\
\hspace{30mm}2\mu(2,3)+3\mu(2,4)+\mu(0,5)\\
\hspace{30mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{3mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{3mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\\
\hspace{15mm}2[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(3,3)\hspace{1mm}]+5\mu(2,4)+4\mu(1,5)+\mu(0,6)\\
\hspace{50mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{3mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{3mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\\
\hspace{50mm}5\mu(3,4)+9\mu(2,5)+5\mu(1,6)+\mu(0,7)\\
\hspace{55mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{6mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{6mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\hspace{6mm}\swarrow\hspace{5mm}\searrow\\
\hspace{40mm}5[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(4,4)\hspace{1mm}]+14\mu(3,5)+14\mu(2,6)+6\mu(1,7)+\mu(0,8)\\
\ldots
\end{equation}

I created a function noted as $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,R)$, where $\beta=0,1,2...$ represents the row number, $\alpha=1,2...$ represents variation, $R$ represents the column of a row.  using the illastrations above I created some examples but I noted $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,R)$as $\binom{\beta}{R}_\alpha$ and I did not include the arrows.

If $\alpha=1$ and $e =0$

\begin{equation}
\hspace{5mm}\binom{0}{0}_1\mu(0,1)\\
[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(1,1)\hspace{1mm}]+\binom{0}{0}_1\mu(0,2)\\
\hspace{25mm}\binom{1}{0}_1\mu(1,2)+\binom{1}{1}_1\mu(0,3)\\
\hspace{15mm}[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(2,2)\hspace{1mm}]+\binom{1}{0}_1\mu(1,3)+\binom{1}{1}_1\mu(0,4)\\
\hspace{51mm}\binom{2}{0}_1\mu(2,3)+\binom{2}{1}_1\mu(1,4)+\binom{2}{2}_1\mu(0,5)\\
\hspace{45mm}2[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(3,3)\hspace{1mm}]+\binom{2}{0}_1\mu(2,4)+\binom{2}{1}_1\mu(1,5)+\binom{2}{2}_1\mu(0,6)\\
\hspace{65mm}\binom{3}{0}_1\mu(3,4)+\binom{3}{1}_1\mu(2,5)+\binom{3}{2}_1\mu(1,6)+\binom{3}{3}_1\mu(0,7)\\
\ldots
\end{equation}

if $\alpha=2,e=0$:
\begin{equation}
\hspace{5mm}\binom{0}{0}_2\mu(0,2)\\
\hspace{5mm}\binom{1}{0}_2\mu(1,2)+\binom{1}{1}_2\mu(0,3)\\
\hspace{0mm}[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(2,2)\hspace{1mm}]+\binom{1}{0}_2\mu(1,3)+\binom{1}{1}_2\mu(0,4)\\
\hspace{30mm}\binom{2}{0}_2\mu(2,3)+\binom{2}{1}_2\mu(2,4)+\binom{2}{2}_2\mu(0,5)\\
\hspace{15mm}[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(3,3)\hspace{1mm}]+\binom{2}{0}_2\mu(2,4)+\binom{2}{1}_2\mu(1,5)+\binom{2}{2}_2\mu(0,6)\\
\hspace{50mm}\binom{3}{0}_2\mu(3,4)+\binom{3}{1}_2\mu(2,5)+\binom{3}{2}_2\mu(1,6)+\binom{3}{3}_2\mu(0,7)\\
\hspace{30mm}[\hspace{1mm}0=\mu(4,4)\hspace{1mm}]+\binom{3}{0}_2\mu(3,5)+\binom{3}{1}_2\mu(2,6)+\binom{3}{2}_2\mu(1,7)+\binom{3}{3}_2\mu(0,8)\\
\ldots
\end{equation}

if $\alpha=c,e=0$:
\begin{equation}
\binom{0}{0}_c\mu(0,c)\\
\binom{1}{0}_c\mu(1,c)+\binom{1}{1}_c\mu(0,c+1)\\
\ldots\\
\binom{c-1}{0}_c\mu(c-1,c)+\binom{c-1}{1}_c\mu(c-2,c+1)+\ldots+\binom{c-1}{c-2}_c\mu(1,2c-2)+\binom{c-1}{c-1}_c\mu(0,2c-1)\\
[\mu(c,c)=0]+\binom{c-1}{0}_c\mu(c-1,c+1)+\ldots+\binom{c-1}{c-2}_c\mu(1,2c-1)+\binom{c-1}{c-1}_c\mu(0,2c)\\
\end{equation}

I then realized that if I allow.

\begin{equation}
  R_{max}=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \frac{\beta+\alpha+mod_2(\beta+\alpha)}{2}, & \text{if }\beta\geq\alpha \\
    \beta, & \text{if }\beta<\alpha
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

AND

\begin{equation}
  \Gamma=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \frac{\beta-\alpha+mod_2(\beta-\alpha)}{2}, & \text{if }\beta\geq\alpha \\
    0, & \text{if }\beta<\alpha
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

Then the sum can be summarized by:

$$\frac{d^\beta \mu(e,e+\alpha)}{(dx)^\beta}=\sum_{i=0}^{R_{max}}\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,R_{max}-i)\mu(e+i+\Gamma,e+\alpha+\beta-i)$$

And since I've always called $\binom{i}{R}$ the Pascal's Triangle notation I will call $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,R)$ the Variant of Pascal's Triangle notation (VPT)

another notable behavior is When $\beta<\alpha$ then $R_{max}=\beta, \Gamma=0$, remembering $f = e+\alpha$ then $$\frac{d^\beta \mu(e,e+\alpha)}{(dx)^\beta}=\frac{d^\beta \mu(e,f)}{(dx)^\beta}$$ $$\sum_{i=0}^{\beta}\Upsilon_\alpha(i,\beta-i)\mu(e+i,f+\beta-i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\beta}\binom{\beta}{\beta-i}\mu(e+i,f+\beta-i)$$
therefore $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,R_{max}-i)=\binom{\beta}{\beta-i}$ for $\beta<\alpha$

BUT If $\beta\geq\alpha$ then all of the Pascal's rules apply for all $R$'s in $\beta$ EXCEPT when $\beta=\alpha+1$ a the horizontal column of blank space called the "You Shall Not Pass Line", YSNPL, prevents any new functions from becoming created at the beyond or on the line. This is because of the property $\mu(c,c)=0$ and $\frac{d \mu(c,c)}{dx}=0$ prevent any function from going beyond or on that line of 0's.

examples of $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,R)$

In order to understand what I just wrote I created 3 examples classified as functions called Pascal's Triangle Numerical Version (PTN$(\alpha)$), Variant of Pascal's Triangle Numerical Version (VPTN$(\alpha)$), and Variant of Pascal's Triangle $\Upsilon_\alpha$ form (VPTY$(\alpha)$).

Both PTN$(\alpha)$ and VPTN$(\alpha)$ will produce 6 rows of their given sequence.

PTN$(\alpha)$ will produce Pascal's Triangle with $\alpha$ number circles around the left most 1 on a given row, starting with the top row.  The circles represent that part of Pascal's Triangle will not change after it encounter the given VPT.

VPTN$(\alpha)$ will show the VPT in numerical form.

VPTY$(\alpha)$ will produce the VPT in $\Upsilon_\alpha$ form

$
\hspace{10mm}\text{PTN(0):}\hspace{54mm}\text{VPTN(0):}\hspace{30mm}\text{VPTY(0):}\\
\hspace{12mm}(1)\hspace{70mm}1\hspace{40mm}\Upsilon_0(0 \rightarrow 0,0)\\
\hspace{12mm}1,1\hspace{72mm}1\hspace{38mm}\Upsilon_0(0 \rightarrow 0,1)\\
\hspace{10mm}1,2,1\hspace{68mm}1,1\hspace{36mm}\Upsilon_0(0 \rightarrow 1,2)\\
\hspace{8mm}1,3,3,1\hspace{68mm}2,1\hspace{34mm}\Upsilon_0(0 \rightarrow 1,3)\\
\hspace{6mm}1,4,6,4,1\hspace{64mm}2,3,1\hspace{32mm}\Upsilon_0(0 \rightarrow 2,4)\\
\hspace{2mm}1,5,10,10,5,1\hspace{62mm}5,4,1\hspace{30mm}\Upsilon_0(0 \rightarrow 2,5)
$

$\hspace{10mm}\text{PTN(1):}\hspace{55mm}\text{VPTN(1):}\hspace{30mm}\text{VPTY(1):}\\
\hspace{12mm}(1)\hspace{70mm} 1\hspace{40mm}\Upsilon_1(0 \rightarrow 0,0)\\
\hspace{10mm}(1),1\hspace{66mm}1,1\hspace{38mm}\Upsilon_1(0 \rightarrow 1,1)\\
\hspace{10mm}1,2,1\hspace{68mm}2,1\hspace{35mm}\Upsilon_1(0 \rightarrow 1,2)\\
\hspace{8mm}1,3,3,1\hspace{64mm}2,3,1\hspace{33mm}\Upsilon_1(0 \rightarrow 2,3)\\
\hspace{6mm}1,4,6,4,1\hspace{64mm}5,4,1\hspace{31mm}\Upsilon_1(0 \rightarrow 2,4)\\
\hspace{2mm}1,5,10,10,5,1\hspace{58mm}5,9,5,1\hspace{28mm}\Upsilon_1(0 \rightarrow 3,5)\\
$

$
\hspace{10mm}\text{PTN(2):}\hspace{55mm}\text{VPTN(2):}\hspace{30mm}\text{VPTY(2):}\\
\hspace{12mm}(1)\hspace{70mm}1\hspace{40mm}\Upsilon_2(0 \rightarrow 0,0)\\
\hspace{10mm}(1),1\hspace{66mm}1,1\hspace{38mm}\Upsilon_2(0 \rightarrow 1,1)\\
\hspace{8mm}(1),2,1\hspace{62mm}1,2,1\hspace{36mm}\Upsilon_2(0 \rightarrow 2,2)\\
\hspace{8mm}1,3,3,1\hspace{64mm}3,3,1\hspace{33mm}\Upsilon_2(0 \rightarrow 2,3)\\
\hspace{6mm}1,4,6,4,1\hspace{60mm}3,6,4,1\hspace{31mm}\Upsilon_2(0 \rightarrow 3,4)\\
\hspace{2mm}1,5,10,10,5,1\hspace{58mm}9,10,5,1\hspace{26mm}\Upsilon_2(0 \rightarrow 3,5)\\
$

$
\hspace{10mm}\text{PTN(3):}\hspace{55mm}\text{VPTN(3):}\hspace{30mm}\text{VPTY(3):}\\
\hspace{12mm}(1)\hspace{70mm}1\hspace{40mm}\Upsilon_3(0 \rightarrow 0,0)\\
\hspace{10mm}(1),1\hspace{66mm}1,1\hspace{38mm}\Upsilon_3(0 \rightarrow 1,1)\\
\hspace{8mm}(1),2,1\hspace{62mm}1,2,1\hspace{36mm}\Upsilon_3(0 \rightarrow 2,2)\\
\hspace{6mm}(1),3,3,1\hspace{58mm}1,3,3,1\hspace{34mm}\Upsilon_3(0 \rightarrow 3,3)\\
\hspace{6mm}1,4,6,4,1\hspace{60mm}4,6,4,1\hspace{31mm}\Upsilon_3(0 \rightarrow 3,4)\\
\hspace{2mm}1,5,10,10,5,1\hspace{52mm}4,10,10,5,1\hspace{26mm}\Upsilon_3(0 \rightarrow 3,5)\\
$

Remember $\alpha$ represents a variation of Pascal's Triangle, $\beta$ represents a row in $\alpha$ and $R$ represents a column in $\beta$.  One should have noticed for each $\alpha$ there is a invisible line where no new number exists on or to the left of that line, YSNPL.  One should have noticed for every column in $\beta$ the top right column and the top left column sum together in the row underneath, $\beta+1$, to create a new column in between both of the original columns.

While researching this phenomena I produced some results for $\alpha=1,2,\infty$

\begin{equation}
  \Upsilon_2(\beta+1,R)=\Upsilon_1(\beta,R) \text{ can be found in }\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \frac{R+1}{\beta+1}\binom{\beta+1}{(\frac{\beta-R}{2})}, & \text{if  }R<\beta \text{ and } mod_2(\beta-R)=0\\
    , & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

let $\eta=2R-mod_2(\beta+\alpha-1)$

if maximuim $R$ = $R_{max}$

$$\Upsilon_1(R,\beta)=\Upsilon_2(R,\beta+1)=\frac{\eta+1}{\beta+1}\binom{\beta+1}{\frac{\beta-\eta}{2}}$$

I found this by creating my own variant from the formula given in [A008313](https://oeis.org/A008313)

$\Upsilon_3$ in [A026009](https://oeis.org/A026009) EQ UNKNOWN

$\Upsilon_4$ in [A026022](https://oeis.org/A026022) EQ UNKNOWN

Since YSNPL only exists if $\beta=\alpha+1$ and $\beta\neq\infty$ if $\beta$ is finite.  Therefore the following statement must be true.$$\Upsilon_\infty(R,\beta) = \binom{R}{\beta}$$
My Question: Is this a known pattern?  Are there other known $\alpha$'s?  This code can find any triangle with a given $\alpha,\beta$

`def tri(alpha,beta) :
    if alpha > 0 :
        D = [0]*((beta)//2+alpha); D[0] = 1
        b = False; h = 1
        for i in range(beta) :
            print([D[z] for z in range(0,h,1)])
            if i < alpha-1 :
                for R in range(h-1, -1, -1) : D[R+1] += D[R]
                h += 1
            else :
                if b :
                    for R in range(h, -1, -1) : D[R] += D[R-1]
                    h += 1
                else : for R in range(0, h-1, 1) : D[R] += D[R+1]
                b = not b
tri(1,10)`

Comment: Where you wrote $\alpha{\leq}\beta{\leq}i$ I changed it to $\alpha\leq\beta\leq i$ simply by changing the code from \alpha{\leq}\beta{\leq}i to \alpha\leq\beta\leq i.  Why do you make that extra effort to put in those {curly braces} whose only effect is to prevent proper spacing? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I thought I always had to use the brackets to separate known words from characters and numbers which I believed included known words.  But thank's you for the assistance.

Comment: To write $\int_0^{12}$ you write \int_0^{12}, and if you omit the braces you see $\int_0^12$.  To write $\frac 1 {12}$ you can write \frac 1 {12} and if you omit the braces you see $\frac 1 12$.  For $\int_0^\infty$ you can write \int_0^\infty but for $\int_0^{+\infty}$ you write \int_0^{+\infty} and if you omit the braces you see $\int_0^+\infty$.  Those are some examples of what braces do. $\qquad$

Comment: Binary relation symbols and binary operators have some space before and after them, as in $5+3=8$, coded as 5+3=8, and if you write 5{+}3{=}8 then there's nothing before or after the "+" or the "=" so that space does not appear and you see $5{+}3{=}8$ instead of $5+3=8$. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't see where you actually define $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,\gamma)$.

Comment: @joriki I'm Trying to find $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,\gamma)$.  I am only a undergraduate so my terminology is very limited but the function $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,\gamma)$ should produce these results.

Comment: Are you saying that all you know about $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,\gamma)$ is these examples and you're looking for a general form that will produce these values? If so, what do you mean when you say that you "figured out" $\Upsilon_\infty(\beta,\gamma)$? Does this denote the limit of $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,\gamma)$ for $\alpha\to\infty$? If so, how can you "figure out" this limit if you don't have a general form for $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,\gamma)$ yet?

Comment: @joriki Yes the general form of $\Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,\gamma)$ should produce these results and $lim_{n{\rightarrow}\infty}\Upsilon_n(\beta,\gamma)\neq\Upsilon_\infty(\beta,{\gamma})$.  The $\alpha$ represents the left side cut off point on Pascals Triangle.  So if $\alpha$ = T then I use the techniques for producing Pascal's Triangle but only add T number of "1"s on the left side, including the first "1", and then I stop adding anything past that point.  So $\Upsilon_\infty(\beta,\gamma)$ represents a inifite number of "1" 's which should produce Pascal's Triangle.  srry bout gamma

Comment: This is still quite opaque to me. I think you need to specify much more clearly (in the question, not just in comments) what you know and what you're trying to find out. For instance, what you wrote in the above comment was not at all clear to me from the present phrasing of the question.

Comment: @joriki Does this make more since?

Comment: Yes, I can now figure out from the description and the examples what you mean; though I still think it would be a lot clearer if you gave a definition instead of mostly relying on examples.

Comment: @joriki How would I give a definition?

Comment: Something roughly like "Form Pascal's Triangle as usual, with each number the sum of the two numbers to its top left and top right (using $0$ for missing numbers), but, starting at row $\alpha$, omit $\left\lfloor\frac{\beta-\alpha}2\right\rfloor+1$ numbers on the left." I'm not sure about the details; that's just to give you an idea how to do it. You could then still use examples to clarify and illustrate, but at least one would have an explicit description of what you're doing instead of having to reverse-engineer it all from the examples.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:undergraduate-research] tag. It is being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
  \Upsilon_\alpha(\beta,R)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \binom{\beta}{R}, & \text{if }\beta\leq\alpha  \\
     \binom{\beta}{R}, & \text{if }\beta\leq R+\alpha  \\
    \binom{\beta}{R}-\binom{\beta-\alpha}{R}, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}